# Get names from database and limit

Tags: database

I need to show a list of user names in my site.

PHP Code:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT name FROM dle_users WHERE user_group=1");
```

Problem is, i cant show 10 or 20 names, with this code i just can show 1 name in list.

Second question is, if i want to get names from 2 or 3 user groups, how i can do that?
in that code my user group is:

```
user_group=1
```

how i can show users from group 1 and 2 or 3?

and my last question,
i have 2 table in my database, in "dle_users" i have names, and in other "dle_phone" i have phone numbers. now how i can select and show useres name and phone numbers from group 1 in "user_group" and phone numbers from "user_phone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can show nothing with one line of code**

> with this code i just can show 1 name in list.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT name FROM dle_users WHERE user_group=1");
```

first you told us:

> Problem is, i can't show 10 or 20 names, with this code **i just can show 1 name** in list.

then you ask in a comment

> how can i show only 10 names, i have 200 names in user_group, how can i
>   **show only 10 user names**

what now ?

you have to iterate through object $sql. (for only 10, set LIMIT 10)

```
if ($sql = $db->query("SELECT name FROM dle_users WHERE user_group=1 LIMIT 10")) {
        while($obj = $sql->fetch_object()){
            echo "name :".$obj->name."<br />";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to clearify somethings in your question what do you mean by "i cant show 10 or 20 names, with this code i just can show 1 name in list" because this sql will fetch all name belonging to the user_group=1 and secondly to get every body according to there user_group you can do this by grouping by user_group

Comment: how i can show only 10 name, i have 200 name in user_group, how i can show only 10 user names?

Comment: first i will advise you pick up a book on sql and read and you can do what you want by adding a limit 10 to the end of your sql statement